# Can we access azure web app by private link

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My on premises network is connected to azure over expressroute. Now with the new private link for azure app service, can the **on-prem users** connect to azure app service with private ip, without going over the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Azure Private Link is in Preview and currently supports Azure Storage and SQL Database, not Azure app service.

> Note that several Azure PaaS services such as Azure Storage, Azure
>   Data Lake Storage Gen 2, Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse,
>   Key Vault, Azure Database for MySQL, Azure Database for PostgreSQL,
>   and Azure Database for MariaDB still offer consumption over Private
>   Link in preview. Azure PaaS will soon offer support for consumption
>   over Private Link in general availability.

Read https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/private-link-now-available-in-ga/

Answer (score 1):

Private Link for Azure App Service is now in Public Preview.

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/03/16/Public-Preview-of-Private-Link-on-App-Service.html